# Can we lock a function with a pthreads mutex for all its other calls?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Say a program spawns a thread. That thread calls func1(). However, func1() is also called in various places elsewhere in the main app. If i wrap it in a mutex lock in the thread only, will it be safe for the whole of the app? Or will one have to go in it and lock it? And if in it are other functions that are called by it but also on the main app in various places, does one have to go recursively and lock them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get out of the habit of thinking that you protect functions with mutexes, you don't.

You actually protect *resources* such as variables shared amongst threads.

Once you accept that little pearl of wisdom, you start thinking in terms of what *data* has to be protected and can minimise the granularity of the protections.

For example, if `func1()` and `func2()` both access the shared variable `x`, and you can call `func2()` either from `func1()` or `main()`, you're going to have to engineer a solution that can detect if the mutex is already locked so that `func2()` can claim/release (when called from `main`) or do nothing (when called from `func1()`). Either that or use a recursive mutex.

Functions which are thread-unsafe (such as using static data areas) *can* be protected with mutexes but I find it's usually easier to refactor them so that they're inherently thread-safe (with allocated memory or thread-local storage).

Comment: I find that the need for recursive mutexes is usually a sign that your locks are too course-grained...

Answer (score 0):

You only need to lock shared resources, or anything not thread-local. You should also consider writing your functions to be reentrant whenever possible. Reentrant functions are inherently thread-safe, whereas not all thread-safe functions can be made reentrant.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you declare `static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` in the function and use it, you can accomplish what you want. But making functions which are not reentrant, which have global state, etc. is generally a Bad Thing(tm). Good design is to lock data, and not to have globals (or singletons which is a euphemism for global variables).